# How to call a method from another class, which is in another .java file?

Tags: java, file, class, methods, call

The teacher gave us a .java file in which there is a method that I need to use in order to solve my question.

Here's the question : 
Call the method countEnglishWords() given in the file SentenceChecker. This method takes as input a String and outputs the number of English words it contains.

**My problem is** that I do not know how to call a method which is in another class which is in another .java file!

Comment: you already know what is an object instance?

Comment: try to understand how to create a instance of object, then yourself find solution.

Comment: no, i dont :/ @JohnnyWiller

Comment: I really want to make an answer to you, but it will be worse to your leaning. Read this first: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm

Comment: I kind of understand it, but in my case my class already exists, do I still need to declare it? @JohnnyWiller

Comment: Yes, declaring is the process of tell to java that you want execute something of that class

Comment: Thank you @JohnnyWiller my code doesn't work yet but I can now call the method countEnglishWords!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must ensure that the class & method you're trying to call have appropriate access modifiers (e.g. public). Then from your class' file, you may `import` the SentenceChecker class at the top.

```
String str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet your mom";
SentenceChecker sc = new SentenceChecker();
sc.countEnglishWords(str); // this will call, you could assign any ret result to variable
```

edit:
you don't necessarily need import statement (i.e. files are in same dir).

1. Put your sentence checker in some empty dir, say "/CheckerProgram"
2. Create MySentenceCheckerCaller.java in same directory
3. Edit MySentenceCheckerCaller.java to:

   ```
   public class MySentenceCheckerCaller {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet your mom";
        SentenceChecker sc = new SentenceChecker();
        int wordCount = sc.countEnglishWords(str); // call method, assumes returns an int
        System.out.println("There are " + wordCount + " words in my string.");
      }
    }
   ```
4. Compile MySentenceCheckerCaller.java and SentenceChecker.java
5. Ensure that you have MySentenceCheckerCaller.class and SentenceChecker.class in program directory
6. Run `java MySentenceCheckerCaller` in terminal

Comment: Good example and explanation.